# Making wordpress like url by mod-rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to edit the URL `http://example.com/paper-ads-details.php?req=43674&rnd=130863240`0 into `http://example.com/ads/43674/1308632400` by following rewrite_rule

```
RewriteRule ^ads/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$ paper-ads-details.php?ads&req=$1&rnd=$2
```

But it's not working. I want to just hide the parameters. Any other suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to add `mod-rewrite` as a tag to this question.

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? Do you want to redirect the user to a URL without parameters? Should the parameters still be present in the target script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite confusing, made more so by the sample you provided, but if I understand correctly that you want the URL to contain no more parameters, then you won't have any `$1` or `$2` to work with. These would be the parameters that you match with your regular expression, but your regular expression doesn't match *any* parameter.

So, if you want `/ads` to go to `/paper-ads-details.php?req=43674&rnd=1308632400`, you can simply write a rule that does exactly that:

```
RewriteRule ^ads$ /paper-ads-details.php?req=43674&rnd=1308632400 [L]
```

The above rule will match the URL `/ads` and will call `/paper-ads-details.php?req=43674&rnd=1308632400` every time that URL is requested.

Answer (score 3):

Both your rewrite rules make no sense. There are no `$1` or `$2` and what you are trying to do is impossible as no webserver can guess what the `req` and `rnd` parameters were.

You may be interested in rewriting `http://example.com/ads/43674/1308632400` into `http://example.com/paper-ads-details.php?req=43674&rnd=1308632400`. Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ads/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$ paper-ads-details.php?req=$1&rnd=$2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rewrite: `http://example.com/paper-ads-details.php?req=43674&rnd=1308632400` into `http://example.com/ads?req=43674&rnd=1308632400`, then try this:

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} ^req
RewriteRule paper-ads-details.php?(.*)$ http://example.com/ads?$1 [L]
```

You can validate your rewrite-rule here - http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: +1 merely for pointing to the rewrite rule tester. Very handy.